# Rails 3 help building simple RSS feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create an simple RSS/Atom feed.

The feed should list max 20 konkurrancer.

The title of each konkurrancer should be konkurrancer.name

The rss feed link should be konkurrancer.tracking which is a url

This is my builder:

```
atom_feed :language => 'en-US' do |feed|
  feed.title @title
  feed.updated @updated

  @news_items.each do |item|
    next if item.updated_at.blank?
 for konkurrancer in @news_items

    feed.entry  do |entry|
      entry.tracking
      entry.title item.title
      entry.content item.content, :type => 'html'

      # the strftime is needed to work with Google Reader.
      entry.updated(item.updated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")) 
end
      end
    end
  end
```

I get this error in view:

```
ArgumentError in Konkurrancers#feed

Showing C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/views/konkurrancers/feed.atom.builder where line #9 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Extracted source (around line #9):

6:     next if item.updated_at.blank?
7:  for konkurrancer in @news_items
8: 
9:     feed.entry  do |entry|
10:       entry.tracking
11:       entry.title item.title
12:       entry.content item.content, :type => 'html'
```

My model:

```
class Konkurrancer < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :name, :tracking, :banner1, :banner2, :kategori_id, :udtraekkes, :tid, :vaerdi, 
end
```

Comment: are you sure not `feed.entries` pluralize form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should pass an object to your `entry` method:

> http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AtomFeedHelper/AtomFeedBuilder/entry

```
entry(record, options = {}) public
```

`feed.entry(konkurrancer)` for example

Comment: if I use feed.entry(konkurrancer) I get this error: undefined method `konkurrancer_url' for #<#<Class:0x87ffa68>:0x87fe790>

Comment: It is another headache. Did you read some tutorials or documentation about what you do? Here some simple links http://railspikes.com/2008/10/1/publishing-non-activerecord-objects-in-an-atom-feed-with-rails http://www.papodenerd.net/creating-atom-feeds-with-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Yes I have read the guides and some other guide to create RSS feeds. I can just dont figure it out how to put my RSS feed together.

Answer (score 0):

fl00r had the correct pointer to your problem. A basic example:

```
atom_feed do |feed|
  feed.title "Title"
  feed.updated @articles.first.created_at

  @articles.each do |article|
    feed.entry article do |entry|
      entry.title article.titl
      entry.content article.body, :type => 'html'

      entry.author do |author|
        author.name article.author
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I posted about this recently, see the full how-to (with code) here: http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/14

Comment: I don't understand your models, therefore the example and link. Wild guess: `@news_items.each do |item|  feed.entry item do |entry|`. In this case, @news_items have to be all your items that shall be in your feed.